# Spring RequestEntity<Object> needs Accept header mandatorily when the server fails

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am working with `Spring Framework` version `4.3.6`. 
It works with `RestTemplate` and thus offers support for `XML` and `JSON`

**Reminder**: about `HTTP` methods, for `POST` and `PUT` has sense mandatorily define the `Content-Type` header. It either for `XML` or `JSON`.

I have a situation for `RequestEntity<Object>` about testing:

I have the following creation for `POST`

```
RequestEntity<Object> requestEntity = 
      RequestEntity.post(uri).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                             .header("Accept-Language", locale.toString())
                             .body(entity);
```

Until here it works fine when none exception is thrown by the server. It means, the entity is saved or persisted in the database without problem.

I have a problem when in other testing scenario the entity already exists in the database. I have a `@ControllerAdvice` that works through `@ExceptionHandler`. The server side works how is expected. It catchs the exception and generates an error message but...

...the problem **only** happens with `XML`, I get the following error message (the `@Test` method fails of course)

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '{' (code 123) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]; nested exception is java.io.IOException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '{' (code 123) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
```

I did realize the unique way to avoid that error message is through the following edition:

```
RequestEntity<Object> requestEntity = 
      RequestEntity.post(uri).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                             .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)//<---- new
                             .header("Accept-Language", locale.toString())
                             .body(entity);
```

I am confused why it works, it because for `POST` is not mandatory define the `Accept` header. Even when in the server side I can define for the `ResponseEntity<Object>` (*response*) the `Content-Type` and `Accept` headers to `XML` value, the `@Test` fails. The unique way to solve this is adding for the `RequestEntity<Object>` (*request*) the `.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)` part.

Here the other problem is that we must assume other Java developers using `RestTemplate` are going to create the `RequestEntity<Object>` object with just defining the `Content-Type` and **without** defining the `Accept` header.

**Note:** it fails even when the `RestTemplate` uses the `setErrorHandler` method

Again, it only happens with `XML`, for `JSON` I have the following:

```
RequestEntity<Object> requestEntity = 
      RequestEntity.post(uri).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                             .header("Accept-Language", locale.toString())
                             .body(entity);
```

and always works for valid and invalid (an entity already persisted) scenarios.

What is the best approach to around this situation?

**Alpha**

Even If I do the following edition how was suggested:

```
@Override
public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.favorPathExtension(true)
              .favorParameter(false)
              .ignoreAcceptHeader(false)
              //.defaultContentType(new MediaType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
              .defaultContentType(new MediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
              .mediaType("html", MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
              .mediaType("xml", new MediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
              .mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
}
```

I get the same situation

About `XML`, I don't use `JAXB2` because it does not support *Generic Collections*, thus I use Jackson [jackson-dataformat-xml](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/wiki)

**Important** I only have this situation when is used `RequestEntity<Object>` with `RestTemplate`, for other testings working around

```
ResultActions resultActions =  
      mockMvc.perform(post(uri).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                               .header("Accept-Language", locale.toString())
                               .content(entity)).andDo(print());
```

Observe, there is **no** a `.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)` sentence.

All work fine.

Answer (score 1):

`Application/json` is probably configured as the default media type in your services application somewhere. That is why unless you specify the `Accept` header to be `application/xml`, you are getting json response.

If you want to make `application/xml` your default response media type, you will need to configure the `ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean` (Maybe you are already doing this but for application/json). Something like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  /**
    * Setup a simple strategy: use all the defaults and return XML by default when not sure. 
    */
  @Override
  public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
  }
}
```

You can find this in spring documentation [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc).

The other thing you need to look at is the entity you are using in error scenarios. If it is properly annotated with Jaxb annotations (`@XmlRootElement`)

Comment: Thanks by your answer, see the addition of the **Alpha** section in my original post

Comment: Question: What is the type of 'entity' you are passing in body. And is there a particular reason why you are using 'Object' rather than the type of 'entity' in RequestEntity

Comment: Could be any Entity class, could be for example be `Person`, `Invoice` etc. Each class has annotations of both kind of annotations available from Jackson, it for `JSON` and `XML` (jackson-dataformat-xml). I don't use `JAXB2`

Comment: Can you share sample code from your controller and controller advice you mentioned in your question? Also please provide the error response entity class.

Reason I'm asking for it:
Content-type defines the media type for the request body when you are making the HTTP request and Accept defines the media type for the response you expect to receive. For some reason, in an error scenario the response being returned is defaulting to json. Which makes me question the entity you are sending in response as a result of error handling (Maybe the error response entity does not have jaxb annotations)

Comment: My `ResponseEntity` class created from the server side handled through the `ControllerAdvice` defines the `Content-Type` and/or `Accept` headers according the original `RequestEntity`'s `Content-Type` value defined. The error message is returned through my own `Error` class annotated with `JSON` and `XML` annotations. Of course it `Error` class represents the body of the `ResponseEntity`. For that part, the server does its job how is expected

Comment: In a non-error scenario you get xml back without any `Accept` header specified. In an error scenario, your `Error` class is being returned as json unless `application/xml` is explicitly specified in `Accept` header. Is that not the case? If it is, then server (Exception Handler) is not doing its job as expected. If it is not, then I am misunderstanding the situation here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137893/discussion-between-ritesh-garg-and-manuel-jordan).